# How to convert to datetime if the format of dates changes gradually through the column?

Tags: pandas, datetime, type-conversion

df.head():

```
    start_date  end_date

0   03.09.2013  03.09.2025
1   09.08.2019  14.05.2020
2   03.08.2015  03.08.2019
3   31.03.2014  31.03.2019
4   02.02.2015  02.02.2019
5   21.08.2019  21.08.2024
```

when I do df.tail():

```
        start_date          end_date

30373   2019-07-05 00:00:00 2023-07-05 00:00:00
30374   2019-06-11 00:00:00 2023-06-11 00:00:00
30375   19.01.2017 2020-02-09 00:00:00 #these 2 start dates are just same as in head
30376   11.12.2009 2011-12-11 00:00:00
30377   2019-07-30 00:00:00 2023-07-30 00:00:00
```

when i do

```
df[start_date] = pd.to_datetime(df[start_date])
```

some dates have month converted as days.
The format is inconsistent through the column. How to convert properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dayfirst=True` parameter:

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], dayfirst=True)
```

Or specify format by http://strftime.org/:

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

---

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], dayfirst=True)
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], dayfirst=True)
print (df)
  start_date   end_date
0 2013-09-03 2025-09-03
1 2019-08-09 2020-05-14
2 2015-08-03 2019-08-03
3 2014-03-31 2019-03-31
4 2015-02-02 2019-02-02
5 2019-08-21 2024-08-21
```

Comment: @kaban - I think because I solve this problem more times, sometimes I spent some time looking why my solution not working. And resaon was same problem like you.